# Method of class in module doesn't see my globals()

Tags: python, global

I have a problem with globals using method of class from my testmodule

Example:
Text of my test module:

cat ./testmodule.py

```
class testclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.testfunc()
    
    def testfunc(self):
        print(' '.join(globals()).split(' '))
```

Text of my test class the same:

```
class testclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.testfunc()
    
    def testfunc(self):
        print(' '.join(globals()).split(' '))
```

Text of my test func, nothing new:

```
def testfunc():
    print(' '.join(globals()).split(' '))
```

And go to test it.

```
Python 3.6.6 (default, Aug 13 2018, 18:24:23)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>>
>>> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa='a'
>>>
>>> import testmodule
>>>
>>> class testclass(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.testfunc()
...
...     def testfunc(self):
...         print(' '.join(globals()).split(' '))
...
>>> def testfunc():
...     print(' '.join(globals()).split(' '))
```

Everything is ready, let's test

```
>>> testfunc()
['__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__', '__annotations__', '__builtins__', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'testmodule', 'testclass', 'testfunc']
```

Variable exist

```
>>> testclass.testfunc(testclass)
['__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__', '__annotations__', '__builtins__', 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'testmodule', 'testclass', 'testfunc']
```

The same result, variable exist

```
>>> testmodule.testclass.testfunc(testclass)
['__name__', '__doc__', '__package__', '__loader__', '__spec__', '__file__', '__cached__', '__builtins__', 'testclass']
>>>
```

Variable is lost.

How can i get the same result from testmodule like from testclass and testfunc?

Comment: Python doesn't have process-wide globals, only module-level globals.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
There is a way to using manually defined variables in a module function?
May be not with globals but with something else?

Comment: You don't want to create variables manually like this. How will your code know what variables exist?

Comment: you may find it easiest to just pack 'em all into a module-level dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @chepner's comment: `globals()` returns the module-level variables of the current module only.

- When you define `testfunc()` in the REPL, it is defined as `__main__.testfunc` and invoking `globals()` returns essentially `__main__.__dict__`.
- When defined in your `testmodule`, it is defined as `testmodule.testfunc` and `globals()` returns `testmodule.__dict__`.

If you want `testfunction` to access globals of another module, you need to ensure that `globals()` is called in the lexical scope of the module. The easiest was is to extend `testfunction` to expect a dictionary as argument:

```
## testmodule.py
def testfunc(globals_):
    print(globals_)

## REPL or other module
import testmodule
testmodule.testfunc(globals())
```

### Additional details

- `__main__` isn't defined by default. You need to `import __main__` before you can use it. But you can see that the current module is named `__main__` from the variable `__name__`.
- When you run `python somescript.py`, the contents of the file are executed as the `__main__` module, not as a `somescript` module.
- Python has closures, and functions inside modules behave essentially like closures over the module scope – so I would have expected `globals()` to be a member of every module. Then the following would have yielded the expected result:

  ```
  %% testmodule.py
  def testfunc(globals_):
      print(_globals())

  %% REPL
  import testmodule
  testmodule.testfunc(globals)
  ```

  but again, this returns the globals of only the testmodule. Instead `globals` is defined only in `__builtin__`, and seems to use the scope of the caller as hidden argument. As a consequence:

  ```
  ## REPL
  import testmodule
  testmodule.testfunc(globals) # prints testmodule.__dict__
  testmodule.testfunc(lambda: globals())  # prints __main__.__dict__
  ```

  Normally expect `f` and `lambda: f()` to have the same result.
- You can't rely on `somemodule.__dict__` to be defined. A module may actually choose to return some wrapper object instead of a normal module object, when you import it. Actually, nothing even enforces that `somemodule` has typical module semantics! E.g. try the module:

  ```
  ## somemodule.py -- Please don't actually do this.
  import sys
  sys.modules["somemodule"] = "not a module"

  ## REPL
  >>> import somemodule
  >>> somemodule
  'not a module'
  ```

  A real-world example for such changes would be `os.path`:

  ```
  >>> import os.path
  >>> os.path
  <module 'ntpath' from 'C:\tools\msys64\mingw64\lib\python2.7\ntpath.pyc'>
  ```

Comment: Excellent answer! 
i added `import __main__` to module
and using `__main__.__dict__` instead `globals()`  it's exactly that i need and it works well. Thank you so much!

Comment: For clarification: Avoid double-underscore functions, if possible! They are always meant as an internal field for introspection and for implementing e.g. operator overloading, or other "magic" stuff. E.g. don't call `obj.__len__`, but `len(obj)`. Of course, if you are writing a module for making the interactive shell more convenient, it may be perfectly valid, but generally modules should not depend on values from the `__main__` module, unless explicitly passed as an argument.